# where can I find what each resource type do for azure resource providers

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

for example, I have an application insight. I see a bunch of apiVersions. and it seems like there are different resource types in different apiVersion.

e.g. the latest contains a resource type called actionGroup. and some other version has a resource type called component.

I can't find anywhere that explains what "actionGroup" or "component" do. what are they? why does different version have different resource type. where can I find information about what resource type do for future reference.

I've seen these

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftinsightscomponents

not very helpful in understanding what resource type actually are.

I'm fairly new to azure so a more detailed explanation would be deeply appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure, every resource in the subscription has its own resource type.

The full name of the resource type of `actionGroup` is `microsoft.insights/actionGroups`, it corresponds to the [action group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups) resource. Another is `microsoft.insights/components`,  it corresponds to the [application insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-new-resource) resource.

The API version corresponds to a version of [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) operations that are released by the resource provider. As a resource provider enables new features, it releases a new version of the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

There are many resource providers in Azure. Each resource provider has many resource type. Each resource in Azure belongs to a resource type. For ex.
**Microsoft.Compute** is a resource provider. **VirtualMachines** is resource type in **Compute**.

You can look at the swagger spec of all resource provider [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/master/specification).

[VirtualMachines Spec](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/d9012681815b2e9e7d7281d2da37f8b3f191aacd/specification/compute/resource-manager/Microsoft.Compute/stable/2016-03-30/compute.json#L1088)